# Problem with Stock Quote from Google Finance

Tags: javascript, html, css, stocks, stockquotes

Below is the example I got from google finance for a stock quote. But it doesnt seem to be working. Stock price isnt displayed.

Thanks

```
<body>
Hello world!
Here is your portfolio:<br/>
  GOOG: <span id=_IG_SYM1_l></span> (<span id=_IG_SYM1_c></span>)<br/>
  AAPL: <span id=_IG_SYM2_l></span> (<span id=_IG_SYM2_c></span>)<br/>
  INTC: <span id=_IG_SYM3_l></span> (<span id=_IG_SYM3_c></span>)<br/>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var quote = new google.finance.Quote();
  quote.enableDomUpdates( { 'GOOG' : '_IG_SYM1', 'AAPL' : '_IG_SYM2', 
    'INTC' : '_IG_SYM3' } );

  quote.getQuotes(["GOOG", "AAPL", "INTC"]);
</script>


<!-- start: javascripts -->

<!-- end: javascripts -->
</body>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I am not getting the stock price.

Comment: Google Finance API was permanently deprecated in Jan 2012, with no replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the example at http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/finance-gadgets.html#JS_API .  If I understand right, that API is only available to gadgets.  It says,

> "Gadgets that use the Market Data API
>   can only run in iGoogle--either
>   production iGoogle, or the iGoogle
>   sandbox."

The [regular Google Finance JS API](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) only allows you to get data associated with a user's portfolio.

Comment: That's the thing.  I don't think there /is/ an API to get raw Google stock quotes on an arbitrary web page.

Comment: There is but it's undocumented. Google does have a stock API you can use. http://jarloo.com/code/networking/google-stock-api/  has an example in ASP.NET. It's all REST based so the language doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need Authenticating to the Google Finance service first.

The AuthSubRequest URL might look like this:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest?
scope=http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.google.com%2Ffinance%2Ffeeds%2F&session=1&secure=0
&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwelcome.
```

http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Authenticating

Comment: Thanks Yada ... went thru the link do i need to add it before calling any API?

Comment: This authentication is for a different API, which does not provide access to raw stock quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried surrounding the span id attributes with quotes?